# Query FxCop For Supported Rules (Using commandline)

Tags: fxcop, fxcopcmd

I would like to run a command to see all rules that FxCop will support (based on the DLLs in its Rules directory).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule list can be viewed in the Rules tab of the FxCop UI (e.g.: http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/screenshot.png).

If you want a text version and don't have a screen clipping tool that will allow you to extract this from the UI, the rules list is pretty trivial to extract with a bit of reflection.  You can either invoke internal types and methods in the FxCop object model to do this, or you can look for concrete classes that implement the `Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.IRule` interface in the rule assemblies.  e.g.:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.EnumerateFxCopRules(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\Rules");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void EnumerateFxCopRules(string ruleDirectoryPath)
    {
        foreach (var ruleAssembly in Program.GetAssemblies(ruleDirectoryPath))
        {
            Program.WriteRuleList(ruleAssembly);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies(string directoryPath)
    {
        var result = new List<Assembly>();
        foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.dll"))
        {
            try
            {
                result.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath));
            }
            catch (FileLoadException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FileLoadException attempting to load {0}.", filePath);
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BadImageFormatException attempting to load {0}.", filePath);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void WriteRuleList(Assembly ruleAssembly)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ruleAssembly.Location);

        foreach (var ruleType in ruleAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => (!t.IsAbstract) && typeof(IRule).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", ruleType.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```